# React native iOS app rejected for in App Purchase

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I never worked on mobile application and I have fixed all the issues from apple team and now the concern is In App Purchase and that's a big confusing part for me, because I don't know anything about it.

How do I manage my packages because everything is being managed from the backend APIs. I have little bit knowledge of app store but the confusing part is how to manage my packages from apple store and how to charge for them?

If anyone has an idea for REACT NATIVE then please guide me, it's very difficult for me now to get approval from the app store.

**Guideline 3.1.1 - Business - Payments - In-App Purchase**

We noticed that your app offers a subscription with a mechanism other than the in-app purchase API.

Specifically, subscriptions to digital videos can be purchased by means other than the in-app purchase API.

**Next Steps**

To resolve this issue, please revise your app to ensure that the subscription for products used within the app is offered using the in-app purchase API, with the exception of the content specified in guideline 3.1.3 of the App Store Review Guidelines.

Please see attached screenshots for details.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get get approval from the app store, you should use in-app purchases. If by any means your app doesn't encourage users to pay for any form of content, please give more context about the purpose of your app. I've also just been through a long review process, so maybe I could give some advice!

---

[Apple's review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#business)

**3.1 Payments**

**3.1.1 In-App Purchase:**
If you want to unlock features or functionality within your app, (by way of example: subscriptions, in-game currencies, game levels, access to premium content, or unlocking a full version), you must use in-app purchase. Apps may not use their own mechanisms to unlock content or functionality, such as license keys, augmented reality markers, QR codes, etc. Apps and their metadata may not include buttons, external links, or other calls to action that direct customers to purchasing mechanisms other than in-app purchase.